# Why is there "はは" in this sentence from a dictionary?

Tags: words

In my dictionary, in an example in the entry for どうやって, there is the word (?) はは at the beginning of the sentence.

> はは どうやって お互い を 知り合った のです か
>
> How did you come to know one another (translation provided by the
> dictionary)

What does that mean?

Nb: The sentence segmentation is that of the dictionary

Comment: Is it an online dictionary? If so, please provide a link. I’m rather surprised a dictionary has an entry for どうやって.

Comment: It is an app called JDict https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ndcsolution.japanesedictionary&hl=fr&gl=US

Comment: I suspect it to be a typo.

Comment: Is any of the options I have listed in my answer not plausible?

Comment: @ChristelleAugustin - The first is possible but not very likely for a standalone sample sentence. The second is even less likely. You don’t address your mother as はは when you are directly talking to her, unless you are joking or something. Besides, it would be written as 母. A typo or bug is more plausible.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is a short/dry laugh "Ha, ha" or possibly an exclamation "Hmm."
はは sometimes means "Yes, Sir!", but it can't be the case.

It lookes to me like an extract from a novel.

Comment: I think the 'Yes, sir' one is also normally 「ははっ」

Comment: @Angelos Exactly.